# How to avoid adding duplicate array entry and instead update the already existing entry

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like `cart` , and user can add desire products to own `cart` *(here is cart is an array)*, but I want to prevent add duplicate `id`, instead add it as new `value` call `q` that show how many times user selected same product. I tried below for loop but no success.

```js
var cart = [];
var i = 1;

$('li').click(function() {
  product = {};

  var id = $(this).data('id');
  product["id"] = id;

  $.each(product, function(i, v) {
    if (v.id == id) {
      console.log('dup');
     //product["q"] = i++;
    } else {
      console.log('not dup');
      //product["id"] = id;
    }
  });

  cart.push(product);
  console.log(cart);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-id="1">Product 1</li>
  <li data-id="2">Product 2</li>
  <li data-id="3">Product 3</li>
  <li data-id="4">Product 4</li>
</ul>
```

The goal `array` should be like this:

```
var cart = [
{id: 1},
{id: 2},
{id: 3},
{id: 4, q: 5} // q is set because user selected id num 4, five times
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create an object you reference by ID instead so you don't have to find the (possibly-matching) item each time?

```js
const cart = {};
$('li').click(function(e) {
  const id = e.target.dataset.id;
  if (!cart[id]) cart[id] = {
    id,
    clickCount: 0,
  }
  cart[id].clickCount++;
  console.log(cart);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-id="1">Product 1</li>
  <li data-id="2">Product 2</li>
  <li data-id="3">Product 3</li>
  <li data-id="4">Product 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. You have an object called `Cart_Item`:

```
var Cart_Item : { id: 0, quantity: 0};
```

You have an array of `Cart_Items`, called `Cart_Collection`.

You have a function to check if it already exists:
(This function returns -1 if it is unique, and else, returns 
the index of found duplicate item [to avoid looping again later in the code to update it])

```
var cartItemCheckDuplicate = function(id, cartCollection)
{
   for(var i = 0; i < cartCollection.length; i++)
   {
      if(cartCollection[i].id == id)
        return i;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Now, your code partially looks like this:

```
$('li').click(function() {
  product = {};

  var id = $(this).data('id');
  product["id"] = id;
  product["quantity"] = 1; // assumed as default

  var itemDupIndex = cartItemCheckDuplicate(id, cartCollection);
  if(itemDupIndex != -1) // which means it is duplicate
  {
    product['quantity'] = product['quantity']+1;
    cartCollection[itemDupIndex] = product;
  }
  else // it is unique
  {
    cartCollection[itemDupIndex] = product;
  }

});
```